# Property 'recaptchaLoaded' does not exist on type 'IReCaptchaComposition | undefined'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using `Vuejs 3 (composition api)` with `vue-recaptcha-v3` and this this my code in login page

```
import { useReCaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha-v3'
const { executeRecaptcha, recaptchaLoaded } = useReCaptcha()
```

it works perfectly but I have **type** error

[image]

How can I **fix** this ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: i didnt find any solution, 
i'd be better to open issue in their repo

Answer (score 3):

I got identical problem, this worked for me:

```
import { useReCaptcha } from "vue-recaptcha-v3";
let recaptchaInstance = useReCaptcha();
const recaptcha = async () => {
  await recaptchaInstance?.recaptchaLoaded();
   const token = await recaptchaInstance?.executeRecaptcha("login");
  return token;
};
```

I defined recaptchaInstance, and then called recaptchaLoaded() and executeRecaptcha().Vue3 compostion + ts

I hope it hepls!